# I want to calculate the sha256 hashed function for 4digits numbers

Tags: python, sha256, hashlib

I want to calculate the hashed format of the 4 digits password and save it into a dictionary to match it with the password files that I have. But there is a problem. can you help me with this?

```
Hashed_Passwords=list()

for i in range(1000,1010):
    Hashed=sha256(i).hexdigest()
        Four_digits_hashed.append(Hashed)

print(Four_digits_hashed)
```

Comment: `hashlib` works with bytes, not integers. Also, passwords are normally strings, not integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the integer into a string first:

```
from hashlib import sha256
from pprint import PrettyPrinter

four_digits_hashed = {}
for i in range(1000, 1010):
    hashed = sha256(str(i).encode('ASCII')).hexdigest()
    four_digits_hashed[i] = hashed

PrettyPrinter().pprint(four_digits_hashed)
```

**Output:**

```
{1000: '40510175845988f13f6162ed8526f0b09f73384467fa855e1e79b44a56562a58',
 1001: 'fe675fe7aaee830b6fed09b64e034f84dcbdaeb429d9cccd4ebb90e15af8dd71',
 1002: 'b281bc2c616cb3c3a097215fdc9397ae87e6e06b156cc34e656be7a1a9ce8839',
 1003: '8c9a013ab70c0434313e3e881c310b9ff24aff1075255ceede3f2c239c231623',
 1004: '75992a5ac67ff644d3063976c2effd10bdd93fcc109798e3d5c1acf2e530d01a',
 1005: '7f861bcee185de001377d79e08af62e94b1e7718e2470e08520c917f8d953602',
 1006: '478c4ffb1cbcea37956a748e6c19d8eadd0a47e86f5e308d26cad39453b5d1ab',
 1007: '2c8b871e52d4e5f5db5ff84a82a45327e20df77edef961c4b6fa0e9c3d97ce5b',
 1008: '9aaf689fbcdfe9f64a071f9cbe28ae44193fa218e72af24456f44bed64583b4d',
 1009: '6ad4a6b1e5ea5569795e516d71909e0ce4809d9dc983d2c219144f684f816e12'}
```

Comment: that's great. Also the pprint library seems helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hashing algorithms work on raw bytes, not `int`s. If you just want to hash the stringified form of an `int`, do:

```
Hashed=sha256(str(i).encode()).hexdigest()
```

which stringifies the `int`, then encodes it to UTF-8 `bytes` (equivalent to ASCII in this case, since the string form uses solely ASCII digits) to provide it in a format `sha256` understands.

Comment: Oh! I got it. Thank you so much bro!